# run pipeline with two different config files in Snakemake

Tags: python, snakemake

I have a relatively long data analysis pipeline, with several modules, that creates a number of output files and plots. I would now like to be able to run this pipeline relatively easily but with two different sets of parameters (or more) stored in two separate config.yaml files.

In particular, I would like to easily run the whole pipeline for one config file, the other, or both at the same time. The outputs would then be stored in two different folders.

### Try 1

As a first try, I just used the `expand()` function. But this is not accepted in the `configfile:` definition, and I get the following error:

```
TypeError in line 4 of /Users/user/Documents/Projects/Snakefile:
stat: path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike or integer, not list
  File "/Users/user/Documents/Projects/Snakefile", line 4, in <module>
  File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/pain/lib/python3.10/genericpath.py", line 19, in exists
```

My Snakefile looks like this:

```
from snakemake.utils import min_version
min_version("6.0")

configfile: expand("configs/config_{QC_level}.yaml", QC_level = ["lowQC", "highQC"])

if 'use_conda' in config and config['use_conda']:
    workflow.use_conda = True

rule all:
    input:
        expand('results_{QC_level}/cell_prop/cell_proportions.csv', QC_level = ["lowQC", "highQC"])

module QC:
    snakefile: "rules/QC.smk"
    config: config

use rule * from QC as QC_*
```

### Try 2

Since the first way did not work, I thought I could just make a config file with the file paths to the two config files containing the parameters:

```
highQC: "configs/config_highQC.yaml"
lowQC: "configs/config_lowQC.yaml"
```

And then adapt the Snakefile the following way:

```
from snakemake.utils import min_version
min_version("6.0")

configfile: "configs/config.yaml"

if 'use_conda' in config and config['use_conda']:
    workflow.use_conda = True

rule all:
    input:
        expand('results_{QC_level}/cell_prop/cell_proportions.csv', QC_level = ["lowQC", "highQC"])


module QC:
    snakefile: "rules/QC.smk"
    config: config[{QC_level}]

use rule * from QC as QC_*
```

Of course, this doesn't work either and throws the following error:

```
NameError in line 16 of /Users/user/Documents/Projects/Snakefile:
name 'QC_level' is not defined
  File "/Users/user/Documents/Projects/Snakefile", line 16, in <module>
```

I'm sure there must be an easy way to do this. One of the reasons I want to proceed this way is because I will reuse this pipeline for other datasets, each time with a different set of parameters. And as anyone knows, it can be difficult to remember the parameters used for a certain pipeline even after a few days. So if possible I would like to avoid as much as possible any inputs from the command line and/or changes to the Snakefile for running the pipeline with different sets of config files.

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple level dict in your config, e.g.

```
param1:
  low: "low quality thing" 
  high: "high quality thing"
```

But then you need to explicitly refer to `config['param1']['{QC_level}']`

You can have multiple `configfile:` directives, but I don't think that helps you.

Supplying a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would help.